# Question id a derivative on a Hilbert space

Tags: analysis, derivatives, hilbert-spaces

On a Hilbert space $H$;

i have this function: $\tilde{f}(x)=f(x)+p(||x||)(x_0,x)$ 
where $x_0\in H, p\in C^2([0,\infty),\mathbb{R}),f\in C^2(H,\mathbb{R})$

i want to caculate $\tilde{f}', \tilde{f}''$, i calculate $\tilde{f}'$ :

$\tilde{f}'(x)=f'(x)+p'(||x||)\displaystyle\frac{x}{||x||}(x_0,x)+p(||x||) x_0$

but i have i big problem with $\tilde{f}''$ i don't know how to write it

Please help me

Thank you.

Comment: The derivative must be a **linear function** in each point of $H$. Remember http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659712/derivative-on-hilbert-space.

Comment: i don't understand ?

Comment: First, write **correctly** the first derivative. If $f:E\longrightarrow F$ and $z\in E$, then $f'(z):E\longrightarrow F$ and is linear. (variable changed because possible confusion)

Comment: Then read again the **definition** of derivative for functions between normed spaces. Namely, if $f:E\longrightarrow F$, then $f:E\longrightarrow {\mathcal L}(E,F)$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative

Answer (score 0):

Idea: the second derivative of the sum is the sum of second derivatives, so
$\tilde f'' = f''+\cdots$.

Idea for the derivative of $x\mapsto p(||x||)(x_0,x)$: chain rule.

Same idea that in the previous exercise ([Derivative on Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659712/derivative-on-hilbert-space)): do first in ${\Bbb R}^n$ and generalize.

Comment: i have a real problem i don't understand! how to write ?

Comment: $\tilde{f}''(x)=f''(x)+\displaystyle(\frac{x}{||x||}) p''(||x||) \frac{x}{||x||}(x_0,x)+(\frac{1}{||x||} id -\frac{<x,.>}{||x||^3}x)p'(||x||)(x_0,x)+p'(||x||)\frac{x}{||x||}x_0+\frac{x}{||x||}p'(||x||)x_0$